# Application packaging

Tags: c#, package, setup-project

I'm using Visual Studio to create my installation package.

My application use some bitmap and other data file. I currently include these files in my setup project.

Is there a way to embed these file in a kind of bundle package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty difficult to do cleanly with the Visual Studio deployment packages.

The issue you will run in to is that in order to use the bitmap, you will be required to extract it to a temp folder to use it.  It is possible to do, however.

Right click your setup project and choose "Add > File..." to add the bitmap to your project.

You can then use the file on your user interface by right clicking the setup project and choosing "View > User Interface", choosing each screen and setting the "BannerBitmap" property.

If you want to output it along side your application, you choose "View > File System", choose the "Application Folder" and add the file there.